# Are questions about teaching Math to Secondary Level students fair game?

Tags: discussion

I'm currently teaching science at a secondary level in Thailand, but it's looking more and more like I'm going to have to take over for the Math teacher - who is leaving - next semester.  This is upper secondary level mathematics, so we're talking Algebra II, Trigonometry, and basic, basic Calculus.  I majored in Physics and Computer Science, so I've got a pretty strong math background. But in thinking about how to present these topics and making sure I hit all the important points when giving a lesson, it would sure be nice to have Math.se as a resource.

So may I ask questions about how to teach Math at the secondary level?  What sort of questions would be kosher and what wouldn't?

Comment: See existing questions tagged [`teaching`](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) and some of those tagged [`intuition`](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intuition). Do your questions resemble these?

Comment: At some point in the intervening nine years, a math educators site was established. Currently in beta. https://matheducators.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would benefit math.SE to spawn a math-teaching forum.

Until that channel exists, as far as instructional questions are specific to mathematics, they are on-topic for the site, and in any case a permissive approach is in order.  Mathematical pedagogy is not easily separable from mathematics and entails many purely mathematical questions.

A [pedagogy] tag seems to be the current most descriptive contender for labelling the teaching postings.  [Instruction], [teaching] and [education] have additional connotations of institutional employment, enrollment or administrative work.  Meta thread with proposals on how to tag teaching-related postings: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/496/the-difference-between-teaching-and-education

Comment: If you think it deserves its own stackexchange site, feel free to propose one on [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). There are already several proposals for sites about teaching specific subjects.

Comment: At the moment I'm not familiar enough with SE and its site creation process to be an ideal initiator of such a group (e.g., I have no idea what "commits" mean).  But I will certainly look into it if the process does not seem to happen naturally.

Answer (score 7):

A thing to keep in mind is the forum is not for discussions, it is for questions that have answers -- in particular "correct" answers.  Many aspects of teaching are subjective.  Some are particular to cultures. So you might have a hard time avoiding those potential pitfalls.  But it can be done.  The forum also has ways of blurring some of the boundaries -- the "community wiki" mode allows for questions that have multiple correct answers.  A potentially good community wiki question could have the form "what proof of X gives students the best intuition for Y?", for example.

The forum is also young and like any young institution has some growing pains so there's little harm in trying things out, especially since you seem to be so conscientious.